# open source Codec library to make media player in c#.net

Tags: c#, .net

Is their any open source codec library? 
That i can use to make my media player?
i have to make a media player (using c#.net) that would support mp3,mp4, flv and xvid files,

Comment: You will have to make sure how many of these codecs require you to license them and which ones can be used freely within your application.  **The obvious question is what have you tried?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VLC (which in itself is I think a pretty good media player) offers a .Net interface in order to embed it in applications, you can check the [VideoLAN Wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/.Net_Interface_to_VLC) for details (I never used it, but as far as I can see on forums, it works).